# How to get rid of weird outlines on texture-painted areas?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, texture-painting

I don't get these lines when painting directly on the texture uv image - only when I paint directly onto the mesh.

[image]

Anyone experienced this before / solutions? Thanks

Comment: you mean the ones in the right viewport?

Comment: How dense is your mesh? I have a lot of problems painting onto a mesh that has just been quad remeshed and not retopologized into a less dense mesh, as if the computer has a problem with the ray casting for the many tiny faces.